# Tabulator ajaxLoaderLoading not working as expected

Tags: tabulator

`

```html
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
  jQuery('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
  jQuery('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();

  var value1 = window.location.toString();
      console.log(value1);
  value2 = value1.split('=');

      value3i= value2[3].replace("%20"," ");
      value4i= value2[4].replace("%20"," ");

  $.ajax({
                            url : "../php/dw_query_dict.php",
                            type : "GET",
                            data : ({"a": value4i , "b": value3i , "c": value2[2] ,"d": value2[1] }),
                            success : function(data1){
                            console.log(data1);
                            query_sql = data1[0].query;
   table.setData(data1);
   table1.setData(data1);
                            console.log("query:"+query_sql);
   },
                    error : function(data1) {
                    }
            });


                    $.ajax({
                            url : "../php/dw_slow_query_list.php",
                            type : "GET",
                            data : ({"a": value4i , "b": value3i , "c": value2[2] ,"d": value2[1] }),
                            success : function(data2){
                            console.log(data2);
                            table2.setData(data2);
                            },
                    error : function(data2) {
                    }
            });



 var table = new Tabulator("#db-error", {
              // height:"300px",
              layout:"fitColumns",
   ajaxLoader: true,
                            ajaxLoaderLoading:'Loadibg data', 
   ajaxProgressiveLoad:"load",
   ajaxProgressiveLoadDelay: 200,
              columns:[
                     {title:"Info", field:"query",formatter:"textarea", align:"left"},
                     ]
      });

            var table1 = new Tabulator("#db-error1", {
                            // height:"300px",
                            layout:"fitColumns",
   ajaxLoader: true,
       ajaxLoaderLoading:'Loadibg data', 
   ajaxProgressiveLoad:"load",
   ajaxProgressiveLoadDelay: 200,
                            columns:[
   {title:"Host", field:"host", align:"cemnter"},
                            {title:"User", field:"user", align:"center"},
                            {title:"Schema", field:"db", align:"center"},
                            {title:"Lock time", field:"lock_time", align:"center"},
                            {title:"Rows examined", field:"rows_examined", align:"center"},
                            {title:"Rows sent", field:"rows_sent", align:"center"},
   {title:"Count", field:"count", align:"cemnter"},
   {title:"Min", field:"min_time", align:"center"},
   {title:"Max", field:"max_time", align:"center"},
   {title:"Avg", field:"avg_query_time", align:"center"},
   {title:"median", field:"median", align:"center"},
   {title:"95%", field:"95_per", align:"center"},
   {title:"Stddev", field:"stddev", align:"center"},
                            ]
             });

            var table2 = new Tabulator("#db-error2", {
                            // height:"300px",
                            layout:"fitColumns",
   ajaxLoader: true,
                            ajaxLoaderLoading:'Loadibg data', 
   ajaxProgressiveLoad:"load",
   ajaxProgressiveLoadDelay: 200,
                            columns:[
                            {title:"Query timestamp", field:"query_timestamp", align:"cemnter"},
   {title:"Host", field:"host", align:"cemnter"},
   {title:"Query time", field:"query_time", align:"cemnter"},
                            {title:"Lock time", field:"lock_time", align:"center"},
                            {title:"Rows examined", field:"rows_examined", align:"center"},
                            {title:"Rows sent", field:"rows_sent", align:"center"},
                            {title:"User", field:"user", align:"center"},
                            {title:"Schema", field:"db", align:"center"},
                            {title:"Actual query", field:"arg",formatter:"textarea", align:"left"},
                            ]
             });

 </script>
```

I have the below code, but for some reason the 'Loading data' overlay is not working for me. The Ajax call pulls data from a mysql table and takes approximelty 60 seconds to complete. I dont see any changes to the screen while the data is being pulled. I am sure I am missing something important, but I am unable to figure out. Apologies in advance :)

Ps. I am using tabulator v4.5.3. And I have tried Chrome and Firefox browsers to test.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nO1z3.png)

Comment: Progressive load only works when using the `ajaxURL` parameter of the table with a server that returns paginated data.  Because you are loading your data with an ajax call, the table isn't actually doing anything until you call `table.setData()`.  Based on the query, it doesn't look like you will be able to easily return the paginated data. You should probably do something like hide the table and show a loading element. Then in the ajax `success` callback, show the table and hide the loading element.

Comment: That idea helped thanks!